# Does __construct get called on static functions

Tags: php

I have created a class with almost only static functions. Now i want to set some default settings in my class, but i want to use my class without creating an instance of it.

Does the __constructor get called when you use your class without creating an instance of it?

Comment: `__construct` is called only by `new` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__construct() is not being called when calling a static method.

Class::staticMethod() call does not invoke __construct()